# How can I stop OS X from automatically connecting to an NFS server on startup?

Tags: macos, automount, nfs

I upgraded to Lion today, but was having the same problem on Snow Leopard. When I start up my Mac and login, it automatically connects to an NFS server. I know this because I see the server in Finder in the Shared section. I'm assuming I connected to the server at some point in the past, but I'm not sure how to make it stop connecting now. Where can I look? Even after ejecting the server, it reconnects on the next startup. What can I do to make it stop?

Further information - here's what my /etc/auto_home looks like:

```
#
# Automounter map for /home
#
+auto_home  # Use directory service
#
# Get /home records synthesized from user records
#
+/usr/libexec/od_user_homes
```

And running /usr/libexec/od_user_homes produced no output.

The mount doesn't show up in Disk Utility or the Directory Utility, and running `lsof` doesn't show the mount (/CIFS). `df` does show /CIFS and indicates that the Filesystem is `x-browser:`

Here's /etc/auto_master:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
```

And the output from `mount`:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
x-browser: on /CIFS (nfs)
localhost:/gWMIVnK_1WG9ZzUq0q3qb7 on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
```

Comment: This is annoying. My cable modem(bthomehub3) shows up as a share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with CIFS-mount, x-browser… That happened because I tried Sharity 3 and 'deleted' it by putting the icon in the trash, like Mac users usually do. :) But the program was still installed and put the CIFS icon on the Desktop every day.

I solved it using the following Terminal command:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/Sharity3/uninstall
```

Comment: Yes! That solved it - thanks a ton! This has been bugging me for way way too long.

Comment: ? The last comment made on Dec 16 to my answer provided an update that you may be running Sharity. I guess you didn't see it.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to consider using the [NFS Manager](http://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html) application to help you locate and disable the NFS automount. You should refer to [this](http://www.bresink.de/osx/143439/Docs-en/pgs/AutoMount.htm) section of the manual for assistance.

The mount name /CIFS and the lack of NFS information indicates you may be running Sharity. Check if it's installed, using Spotlight. If it is, you can find the documentation [here](http://www.obdev.at/resources/sharity/manual3/en/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. The automounted drive didn't show up in there, though.

Comment: Ok. Can you open a terminal window, type: `/usr/libexec/od_user_homes` and hit return. Is something printed out on the following line? Next, in the same terminal window, type: `cat /etc/auto_home` and let us know what is printed out.

Comment: Thanks again - I updated the question to show the output of these.

Comment: Ok. What does `cat /etc/auto_master` return? Your question initially said NFS, yet a recent edit now also mentions CIFS. What does `mount` return in a terminal window? Finally, from the Finder what does ⌘I (get info) show for the mount type of the volume?

Comment: Updated my question with more info. Finder shows that the Kind on the CIFS folder is Sharepoint. I don't see anything in Finder about a mount type.

Comment: You may be running Sharity. Check if it's installed, using Spotlight. If it is, you can find the documentation [here](http://www.obdev.at/resources/sharity/manual3/en/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

NFS mounts should show up in Disk Utility.  Open Disk Utility.app (In /Applications/Utilities/) and under the File menu select NFS Mounts. Select the URL of the drive that keeps showing up and click the minus button on the lower left corner of the screen to remove it.

[image: Disk Utility - NFS Mounts...]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't show up there. I'm currently chatting with Lyken and have discussed this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/883/discussion-between-josh-brown-and-lyken

Answer (score 3):

Check your start up items in system preferences. It might be in there which would be why it keeps auto mounting.

Comment: I checked, and all I see are a few apps: iTunesHelper, Alfred, ClipMenu, DTerm, bzbmenu, Dropbox. I'd guess none of those are doing this, but maybe...

Comment: Was this machine in a managed environment?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Were you logging onto a domain for this machine at any time?

Comment: No, but I did log onto a domain with my previous machine and used Migration Assistant to migrate everything from that one to my new machine. So it's possible something got migrated.

Comment: Yeah I would say something has been migrated with a config file. Check disk utility to see if its defined in there. File>NFS Mounts

Comment: @Lyken let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/883/discussion-between-josh-brown-and-lyken)

Answer (score 3):

save this as ~/Library/LaunchAgents/cifs.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>localhost.CIFS</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/sbin/umount</string>
        <string>/CIFS</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(Translation: "whenever I login, unmount /CIFS")

I know it's not an answer, but since several reasonable attempts have been made to figure it out, I thought it might be time to suggest a "Well at least this way it won't keep annoying you" alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, does `lsof` show which files are actually open on the share? Does `df` actually show a mounted filesystem or is Finder being helpful and pinging an available share and just connecting to see what the share points might be, not actually mounting a true filesystem.

Perhaps some program you are unaware is causing the mount.

There are lots of places you can cause a remote file system to mount - and we're all guessing them one by one (my guess comes in a moment). If you can pinpoint the exact files that are open - you might realize that's where the mount is happening and not have to disable automatic mounts (by disabling the launchd job com.apple.autofsd). One last tack to track down the cause of the mount might be to change the password (or require one) on the share temporarily and see what process throws an error on the mac.

Now to the guessing part ...

Automatic mounts can also be configured in the Users & Groups pane.

Do check that you haven't set up AutoMounts and several other settings that can cause file systems to be mounted automatically by looking over the **Viewing** pop up menu as well as perhaps just detaching from any directory servers that could push those mounts onto your mac as a matter of policy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I ran `lsof | grep CIFS` (the name of the mount) and didn't get any output. `df` does show the `/CIFS` mount - the Filesystem is `x-browser:` I also checked Directory Utility and didn't find any mounts or Automounts.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question... can't you just drag the server to the Eject button (trash can)?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but it's a pain to do that every single time I start up my computer...

Answer (score 1):

Your mac is doing this because of cached MCX. It was at some point or it thinks it has or still is bound to a directory server, most probably Open Directory on OS X Server. I will bind it to whatever server you had bound to and do a clean unbind. also check on the server to see if you can see this computer account (you might have to enable the advanced view target icon tab, to be able to search via mac address etc and see hidden accounts)

Comment: So how do I resolve this on my Mac? I don't have access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, I was seeing three Sharepoint servers show up in the Shared section of my Finder window.  I went to Users & Groups and disabled a Guest User account that was set up on my laptop.  Once I deselected "Allow guests to log in to this computer" and "Allow guests to connect to shared folders" the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, I had used [NFS Manager](http://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html) to set up an automount, but after upgrading to Yosemite, the application no longer works properly. However, it displayed my mount and through [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120717055242729), I was able to locate where the mount was configured. (Like the OP, my automount info was not in /etc/auto_master or any of its supporting files).

The supposedly correct way to remove the undesired link:

```
sudo dscl
> cd /Local/Default/mounts
> ls
freenas:/mnt/vol_home/nfs_home.plist
> read freenas:\/mnt\/vol_home\/nfs_home.plist
  --various output here showing my configuration --
> delete freenas:\/mnt\/vol_home\/nfs_home.plist
  -- failed due to Invalid Path DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
  -- no combination of \, %2F, or quotes was successful
```

And the apparently less correct, brute-force method (use `sudo cp -p` to make a backup of the file first if you wish):

```
sudo rm /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/mounts/freenas:%2Fmnt%2Fvol_home%2Fnfs_home.plist
```

You may be able to avoid reboot via:

```
sudo automount -cv
sudo umount /nas     (whatever your mount point is)
sudo rmdir /nas
```

But it may disallow the umount due to files still being in use.