# Prevent mounted volumes/folders from clogging the desktop on log in

Tags: macos, startup, mount

I have a lot of volumes (folders) mounted from remote machines, about 10 of them, which I set to be mounted automatically when I'm logging in by adding them to the **Login Items** list in **Users & Groups**. Of course, I made sure to tick the **Hide** check box of each of the volumes, yet OS X opens each of the folders whenever I log in so I have to close them one by one manually.

When an application starts, the hide button makes sure no windows are drawn visibly. Can Finder be configured to respect the "hide" flag similarly?

Comment: How do you add them to Login Items?

Comment: @Mark By using the plus button beneath the login items list in Users & Groups > Login Items

Comment: That action tells the computer to open the Folder (so open in Finder) not just mount it, so we need another way of mounting the filesystems

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20185/37797) for two ways to hide Finder windows for windows opened with login items.

Comment: Does this prevent the icons from displaying or the windows from opening?

Comment: This only controls whether the shared volumes have icons on the desktop. It does not prevent finder from opening one view of each share that mounts. Basically, the OP is looking for a way to make the "Hide" flag hide the windows shares pop up just like starting a hidden app hides the windows for that app.

Comment: Sorry, mixed it up and provided an irrelevant answer. Have fixed that now.

Comment: Can you verify the link please? Doesn't seem to work