# Two drobo NAS on one network causes premature  'Server has closed down' events. 

Tags: nas, afp, bonjour

We have a Drobo setup with a fixed IP on ethernet which we've named BoxA. It shows up in the finder list, everyone can connect to it and share files.

We brought a second Drobo to backup the first, this was given a different fixed ip and a different name BoxB.

When we connect BoxB to the network all the clients which are connected to BoxA receive the message "BoxA has closed down" clicking on BoxA on the finder reveals the content of BoxB.

Any idea what might be causing Finder to display this message? Why would it see two different network servers as the same?

Comment: You might be better served by asking on Drobo's [support website](http://support.drobo.com/) or contacting their [support staff](http://www.drobo.com/support/contact-support.php).

Comment: Have done, but not much luck :(

Comment: Can you (are you) access (ing) the drobo shares using mac only software or is drobo software loaded on the macs that have the issues? Perhaps adding software details might help if different versions have different functions or bugs.

Comment: So don't use a fixed IP address. Allow your router to handle the DHCP. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @bmike We are accessing them using regular Finder. Drobo tools are only loaded on a couple of the machines and we get the same error.

Comment: @slick We've tried DroboB in DCHP mode but by default it picks the wrong subnet and is invisible so we have to provide an IP.

Comment: Wow - if finder is getting disconnected, then the drobo have to be talking to themselves and working together to start/stop shares - that would be amazing (and boggles my mind that would get programmed into those)

Comment: @bmike My only guess is that somewhere they have the same identifier (netbios?, afp?) and finder is getting mixed up between the two, which sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that along with the real static IP that is set in the Drobo Dasbhoard each Drobo was assigned a [local link address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). After some digging around in the firmware I found that both Drobo's were just binding themselves to: 169.254.213.234 without checking if another device was using this address.

This is why Finder was showing DroboA as DroboB as it was using the local link address to resolve the DroboA.local address.

If you install Drobo Apps and Dropbear you can SSH into the device and adjust the address used, these changes probably won't stick around after a firmware update but you need to adjust the IP in following files:

- /etc/init.d/net_config
- /etc/udcpc.sh

Now DroboA is bound to 169.254.213.234 and DroboB is bound to 169.254.213.233 both appear as separate entries in the finder and work as I first expected. I've filed a bug with Drobo as I don't see why it should assign an IP without first checking if it already exists.

Comment: Wow! That is egregious behavior for a networked device - but makes prefect sense in hindsight. Great catch!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing each in it's own [NetBIOS Domain Name](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961556.aspx) to keep them from chatting/colliding on a shared port or name?

Comment: Is there a terminal command to display netbios names on the current network?

Comment: I don't know of a command line, but you could fire up the Directory Utility and **View** in node **/Search** and see if any of the following will browse your current network: SharePoints, NetGroups (see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17937/how-can-i-stop-os-x-from-automatically-connecting-to-an-nfs-server-on-startup/20220#20220 ) for more starting details